# Functional API Keras alternate solution for predict_classes()

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, convolution

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440274/training-on-the-merged-layer-in-keras) for my previous question for background information. As per [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42456188/7103753) suggested by [Nassim Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7137636/nassim-ben). I trained model of two-path architecture using functional API. Now  I feel stuck as I need to predict the class of each pixel. here is the code for the same:

```
    imgs = io.imread(test_img).astype('float').reshape(5,240,240)
    plist = []

 # create patches from an entire slice
            for img in imgs[:-1]:
                if np.max(img) != 0:
                    img /= np.max(img)
                p = extract_patches_2d(img, (33,33))
                plist.append(p)
            patches = np.array(zip(np.array(plist[0]), np.array(plist[1]), np.array(plist[2]), np.array(plist[3])))

    # predict classes of each pixel based on model
            full_pred = self.model_comp.predict_classes(patches)
            fp1 = full_pred.reshape(208,208)
```

But according to the [github-link](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2524) predict_classes() is unavailable. So my question is there any other alternative that I can try?

Comment: Hi Paul, what do you mean by the class of each pixel? I thought you were predicting the class of a picture?

Comment: Hello Nassim the method predicts the class of a pixel by processing the M×M patch centered on that pixel. The input X of our CNN model is
thus an M × M 2D patch with several modalities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, predict_classes is not available for functionnal models as it might not make sense to use it in some cases.
However, a "one liner" solution exists to this :

```
y_classes = keras.utils.np_utils.probas_to_classes(self.model_comp.predict(patches))
```

This works in keras 1.2.2, not sure about keras 2.0, I couldn't find the function in the source code. But there is really nothing shady about this, your model outputs a vector of probabilities to belonging to each class. What the function does is just take the argmax and outputs the class coresponding to the highest probability.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Nassim, Can you have look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42948903/keras-wrong-image-size?

Answer (score 2):

Nassim answer is great but I want to share with you the experience I have with similiar tasks:

1. **Never use `predict_proba` Keras** for version. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41716380/keras-output-of-model-predict-proba/41729210#41729210) you could find why.
2. Most of methods used for turning predictions into classes doesn't take into account your data statistics. In case of image segmentation - very often detecting an object is more important then detecting a background. For this reason I advise you to use a threshold obtained from a [precision-recall](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html) curve for each class. In this case - you need to set a threshold value for which `precision == recall` (or it's as close as possible). After you obtain the thresholds - you need to write your custom function for a class prediction.